Asyncio CPU bound functions
I have a tornado web app that mostly is async but has large sections of CPU bound work where it iterates over data. Most of the time there are only a few hundred of rows but sometimes it can be tens of thousands which blocks the event loop for a few seconds. I'm wondering the preferred method of converting these sync functions to async. My two options seem like:
# Iterate over rows from db
i = 0
for row in rows:
    i += 1
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    # Do some processing

or
# func being the above code that iterates over rows without sleep
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor, func)

I know to avoid GIL limitations I should use ProcessPoolExecutor but most of the time the number of rows it has to iterate over are pretty small so using a ProcessPoolExecutor might not be worth the overhead.

Use the ProcessPoolExecutor if the CPU requirements can be intensive. The main overhead is the initial creation of the pool whose cost is amortized over the life of the program (be sure to create the pool once and reuse it as necessary) and passing data to and from your func worker if we are talking a lot of data. In your posted code you are passing no data.

This is a pattern that could play nicely running in another thread -
even with the GIL, at least the async loop won't be blocked during the processing.
Moreover, trying a ProcessPoolExecutor instead of the default ThreadPool would take the change of two lines of code (one of which being the import statement for the executor).
The asyncio.Loop.run_in_executor returns a task which can be awaited, standalone (blocking only the current web view function), or run in a specialized async task, apart from the views if that is convenient.
Nowadays, it is also worth taking a look in the Free Threading variation of Python 3.13 - the ThreadpoolExecutor could run in parallel for free, without incurring the serialization overhead innerent to using a ProccessPoolExecutor.
All that said, the strategy of running an await asyncio.sleep(0) from time to time in a CPU bound loop is not bad, and I had used from time to time - however, there are no downsides to use a threadpoolexecutor, and you could just try that first.
